# Record one application only in windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, screen-recording

I'm looking for a software to record a window only (a presentation), For example I only want to record Adobe Connect application, but if Chrome goes to foreground on top of Adobe Connect, record content of Adobe Connect only and hide chrome. Or put Adobe Connect in another desktop and record that second desktop and switch to first desktop while recording second desktop. Is it possible?

I currently run adobe connect in a virtual machine and record on it. but I want a solution without virtual machine.

My OS is Windows 10. I tried many software but they only record active screen only.

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question to include such information as (1) what the purpose of the recording is (e.g., automation or presentation), (2) the operating system and version you are using, and (3) whether you have tried/looked at and eliminated from consideration any extant software. Recent updates of Windows 10, for example, have recording built-in.

Comment: What are you currently using? To my experience, what you describe is standard behavior of screen recording software (unless you specify to record the entire desktop). Further, how much you'd be willing to spend if it comes to paid solutions? Any requirements towards the video format? Must audio be recoded along? PS: You can also consult [these answered questions on Windows screen recording](/search?q=[screen-recording]+[windows]+answers%3A1).

Comment: Have you checked out the Windows Game Bar? There are many articles on the net about using it for your purpose, for example https://www.businessinsider.com/how-to-record-screen-on-windows-10